Saving Tfrs Model
I am trying to train a model using tfrs, so I have successfully trained the model the problem is saving the model, but I keep  getting the error.
WARNING:tensorflow:Model's `__init__()` arguments contain non-serializable objects. Please implement a `get_config()` method in the subclassed Model for proper saving and loading. Defaulting to empty config.


. my model configuration is below:
import keras

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package="user_model")
class UserModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.unique_user_ids = unique_user_ids
        self.user_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,), name = 'user_id', dtype = tf.string),
            tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=self.unique_user_ids,mask_token=None),
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_user_ids) + 1, 32),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='FlattenUser')
        ])

        # self.normalized_timestamp = timestamp_normalization

    def call(self,inputs):
      return tf.concat([
          self.user_embedding(inputs["USER_ID"]),
          # tf.reshape(self.normalized_timestamp(inputs["TIMESTAMP"]),(-1, 1)),
      ],axis=1)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        # Return a dictionary of all initialization arguments
        config.update({"unique_user_ids": self.unique_user_ids})
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        # Use the config dictionary to recreate the model instance
        config["unique_user_ids"] = keras.layers.deserialize(config["unique_user_ids"])
        return cls(**config)


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package="movie_model")
class MovieModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.unique_item_ids = unique_item_ids
        self.video_embeddings = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,), name = 'item_id', dtype = tf.string),
            tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=self.unique_item_ids,mask_token=None),
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(self.unique_item_ids) +1 , 32),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='itemFlatten')
        ])
        self.unique_country = unique_country
        self.country_embeddings = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,), name = 'country', dtype = tf.string),
            tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=self.unique_country,mask_token=None),
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(self.unique_country) + 1, 32),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='countryFlatten')
        ])

        # self.genre_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        # max_tokens=100)
        self.genre_vectorizer = genre_vectorizer

        self.genre_embeddings = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,), name = 'genre', dtype = tf.string),
            # genre_vocabulary,
            # tf.keras.layers.Embedding(genre_vocabulary.vocab_size(), 32)
            # tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=100),
            genre_vectorizer,
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(100, 32, mask_zero=True),
            tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()
        ])

        # self.genre_vectorizer.adapt(item.map(lambda x: x["GENRES"]))

    def call(self,inputs):
        return tf.concat([
            self.video_embeddings(inputs["ITEM_ID"]),
            self.country_embeddings(inputs['COUNTRY']),
            self.genre_embeddings(inputs["GENRES"]),
        ],axis=1)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        # Return a dictionary of all initialization arguments
        config.update({"unique_item_ids": self.unique_item_ids,
                "unique_country": self.unique_country,
                "genre_vectorizer": self.genre_vectorizer,
        })
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        # Use the config dictionary to recreate the model instance
        config["unique_item_ids"] = keras.layers.deserialize(config["unique_item_ids"])
        config["unique_country"] = keras.layers.deserialize(config["unique_country"])
        config["genre_vectorizer"] = keras.layers.deserialize(config["genre_vectorizer"])
        return cls(**config)

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package="video_recommend")
class VideoRecommender(tfrs.models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.query_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            UserModel(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)
        ])
        self.candidate_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            MovieModel(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)
        ])
        self.task = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(
            metrics=tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
                candidates=item.batch(128).map(self.candidate_model)
            )
        )

    def compute_loss(self,features,training=False):
        query_embeddings = self.query_model({
            "USER_ID":features["USER_ID"],
            # "TIMESTAMP":features["TIMESTAMP"],
        })
        video_embeddings = self.candidate_model({
            "ITEM_ID":features["ITEM_ID"],
            "COUNTRY":features["COUNTRY"],
            "GENRES":features["GENRES"],
        })
        return self.task(query_embeddings, video_embeddings)

    def get_config(self):
       config = super().get_config()
       config.update({
            "user_model_config": tf.keras.layers.serialize(UserModel()),
            "movie_model_config": tf.keras.layers.serialize(MovieModel()),
        })
       return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        user_model_config = tf.keras.layers.deserialize(config.pop("user_model_config"))
        movie_model_config = tf.keras.layers.deserialize(config.pop("movie_model_config"))
        return cls(user_model_config, movie_model_config, **config)


Building the model
model = VideoRecommender()
model.compile(run_eagerly=True,optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))

history = model.fit(combine.batch(500),epochs=1)
index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(model.query_model)
trained_index = index.index_from_dataset(
  tf.data.Dataset.zip((
    item.batch(100).map(lambda x: x["ITEM_ID"]),
    item.batch(100).map(lambda x: {
      'ITEM_ID':x["ITEM_ID"],
      'COUNTRY':x["COUNTRY"],
      'GENRES':x["GENRES"],
      }).map(model.candidate_model)))
)

Running inference and saving the model:
import datetime
user_features = {'USER_ID': tf.constant(['8dfc850afd83aba59c945730db89e59b'])}
_, scores = trained_index(user_features,k=30)

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp:
  path = os.path.join(tmp, "model")
  tf.saved_model.save(
      trained_index,
      path,
      options=tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(namespace_whitelist=["bruteforce"])
  )



error is:
WARNING:tensorflow:Model's `__init__()` arguments contain non-serializable objects. Please implement a `get_config()` method in the subclassed Model for proper saving and loading. Defaulting to empty config.


I have tried registering the model for serialization and added get_config.

Hi @Kunle_adewole The warning you're seeing suggests that there are non-serializable objects in the model's initialization arguments. To address this, you're attempting to implement the get_config() method in your custom model classes.From the code you've shared, it looks like you've implemented the get_config() method in both UserModel and MovieModel classes. However, it seems like you missed implementing the get_config() method in the VideoRecommender class.
